# Computer crashed, all text files in Docx upon startup

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

My computer crashed last night when I was running Spybot Search & Destroy. It might have overheated, because it was pretty a hot day and the bottom of my laptop was also hot. Upon rebooting, **all** of the text files I had in Word Starter 2010 are now either `.docx` files or Notepad files.

I can't open them in Office 2010 because I don't have the full version, and when I try to open them in Word Starter, it says the file couldn't be found. Is there any way I can convert them back to word files and retain formatting, or am I going to have to redo 50 files by hand?

Answer (score 1):

First thing you can try is to try and open one of the files in a word processor supporting .docx format. You can find a list of such software here: [Applications with Open XML support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML#Application_support). I would recommend: [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/), since it supports portable installation so you can put it on a flash drive and have it available at all times.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your file associations for Word Starter got messed up because Spybot did some registry tweaking. You can restore the file associations by doing the following:

1. Open Programs & Features in Control Panel
2. Right click Office Starter 2010, and click **Change**.
3. A window will open asking if you want to **Repair Office 2010**. Proceed with the **repair**.

I had a similar answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/639482/201262).